# BigQuery breaks on `pivot`ing - Invalid field name

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

I'm trying to do a query such as this:

```
select *
from (
    select agent, text, expect
    from `my.table.runs`
)
pivot (
    min(expect) as expect,
    min(agent) as agent
    for agent in ("august-mr")
)
```

but getting an error of

> Invalid field name "expect_august-mr".

If i use an agent name with an underscore like `august_mr` it works fine.
So the *values* in my data are breaking the query.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: `"august-mr"` is a delimited identifier, e.g. a column name. Use single quotes for string literals, like `'august-mr'`.

Comment: that doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add alias to such fields

```
select *
from (
    select agent, text, expect
    from `my.table.runs`
)
pivot (
    min(expect) as expect,
    min(agent) as agent
    for agent in ("august-mr" as august_mr)
)
```